# Compare two lists of same type

Tags: c#

I need to compare two lists of same type. Assume I have CurrentSC List(Current modified data by user) and PreviousSC List(Saved data from database) of below class.

```
public class SoftClose
{
    private int AID = -1;
    private bool _softCloseInd;
    private bool _softCloseEditInd;
    private string _softClosedBy;
    private DateTime _softClosedDate;
    private ReferenceEnums.ActionStatus _status = ReferenceEnums.ActionStatus.NO_CHANGE;
}

        public static void TPostProcessAddRemoveSoftCloseStopPaymentPrefixes(IFPMServiceInternal fpmService, AgreementRevision revision)
    {
        List<SoftClose> psc = null;
        List<SoftClose> csc = null;
        string fanValue = revision.Agreement.FAN;

        psc = fpmService.GetSoftCloseByFAN(fanValue);
        if (psc != null)
        {
            //var currentprefixes = revision.Details.Where(x => x.Prefix != null).Select(y => y.Prefix).Distinct();

            //Create current SoftClose object using revision object
            foreach (var prefix in revision.Details.Where(x => x.Prefix != null).Select(y => y.Prefix).Distinct())
            {
                var newSF =
                      new SoftClose
                      {
                          Id = -1,
                          Status = ReferenceEnums.ActionStatus.NO_CHANGE,
                          AgreementRevId = revision.Id,
                          AgreementId = revision.Agreement.Id,
                          WorkflowStatus = revision.WorkflowStatus,
                          FAN = revision.Agreement.FAN,
                          PID = (int)revision.Agreement.PID,
                          Prefix = prefix
                      };

                csc.Add(newSF);
            }

            //Now you have previous and current softcloses to compare prefixes...
            psc.OrderBy(x => x.Prefix.Id);
            csc.OrderBy(x => x.Prefix.Id);

            for(int i = 0; i < csc.Count; i++)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Lets say I have changed D3 value in PreviousSC to D2 in CurrentSC. Now i need to delete D3 value from database(As D2 value already there in database i don't need to insert) and chnage _status to DELETE and I added D4 value in CurrentSC which is not there is PreviousSC. Now I need to add D4 value in database and assign _softCloseInd and _softCloseEditInd to Y and change _status to ADD.

How to achieve this in best way?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add code that creates `PreviousSC` and `CurrentSC` from it. It is not clear what that `D1`, `D2` and so on means

Comment: Aleks I edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<SoftClose> psc = new List<SoftClose>(){
             new SoftClose(){ID=1, Status = "NO_CHANGE",AID=19, Prefix = "D1"},
             new SoftClose(){ID=2, Status = "NO_CHANGE",AID=20, Prefix = "D2"},
             new SoftClose(){ID=3, Status = "NO_CHANGE",AID=21, Prefix = "D3"},
             new SoftClose(){ID=3, Status = "NO_CHANGE",AID=22, Prefix = "D9"}
                                             };

        List<SoftClose> csc = new List<SoftClose>(){
             new SoftClose(){ID=-1, Status = "NO_CHANGE",AID=19, Prefix = "D2"},
             new SoftClose(){ID=-1, Status = "NO_CHANGE",AID=20, Prefix = "D2"},
             new SoftClose(){ID=-1, Status = "NO_CHANGE",AID=21, Prefix = "D6"},
             new SoftClose(){ID=-1, Status = "NO_CHANGE",AID=22, Prefix = "D4"},
             new SoftClose(){ID=-1, Status = "NO_CHANGE",AID=23, Prefix = "D5"},
             new SoftClose(){ID=-1, Status = "NO_CHANGE",AID=24, Prefix = "D3"}
                                             };

        List<SoftClose> esc = new List<SoftClose>();

        Console.WriteLine("---------Previous List----------");
        foreach (var item in psc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Id:{item.ID}, Desc1:{item.Prefix}, Status:{item.Status}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("---------Current List----------");
        foreach (var item in csc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Id:{item.ID}, Desc1:{item.Prefix}, Status:{item.Status}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");

        var addlist = csc.Where(c => psc.All(p => !p.Prefix.Equals(c.Prefix)));
        foreach (var n in addlist)
        {
            var index = csc.FindIndex(p => p.Prefix.Equals(n.Prefix));
            csc[index].Status = "ADD";
            esc.Add(csc[index]);
        }

        var deletelist = psc.Where(p => p.Status.Equals("NO_CHANGE") && !csc.Exists(c => c.Prefix.Equals(p.Prefix)));
        foreach (var n in deletelist)
        {

            var index = psc.FindIndex(c => c.Prefix.Equals(n.Prefix));
            if (psc.FindIndex(c => c.Prefix.Equals(n.Prefix)) >= 0)
            {
                psc[index].Status = "REMOVE";
                esc.Add(psc[index]);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("---------Effective List----------");
        foreach (var item in esc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Id:{item.ID}, Prefix:{item.Prefix}, Status:{item.Status}");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class SoftClose
{
    public int ID = -1;
    public int AID = -1;
    public int WFID = -1;
    public string Prefix;
    public DateTime SCDATE;
    public string Status;
}
```